# Permission Denied / Operation not permitted

Tags: termux

I was having a issue while experimenting with my samsung android 6.0 Device. I have downloaded Termux( Linux terminal for android which has all linux terminal functionality ). And i have converted my phone into a ssh server using SSH Client app from playstore.

So the main problem is that when i try to generate a ssh key pair using command `ssh-keygen` it works but it stores the ssh key into `data/data/com.termux/files/home/`.shh but i want it in `sdcard/key/` ( I have created a directory name key ). But when i try to generate a key pair in `sdcard/key` it show permission denied. When i try to copy or move from data/data/com.termux/files/home/.shh/ using `cp data/data/com.termux/files/home/.ssh/key_pair sdcard/key` it show me permission denied so i tried to create another folder in sdcard/ and gave it permissions for read-write-execute using `chmod 777 dir_name` it shows me operation not permitted.

So i done a bit research on this topic on google, i found that i have to root my device then i tried to root my device using KingoRoot, iRoot, adb but it showed that `Your device is too strong to bee rooted` in fact i gave those app all permission and there is no antivirus or in built security disabled on my device. Then i thought to directly place it in `sdcard/key` but then i got to know that i cannot move anything from `data/data/com.termux/files/home/.shh`.

And when i tried to move files via ssh server or upload files on my ssh server via `ssh admin@192.168.1.5 -p 2222` using scp command it showed me file not found but the file is in the correct directory and correct path.

And please answer the following questions that i have regarding the issues above that `1> How to move files from localhost to ssh server` `2> how to root device if it is too strong to be rooted(any method)`

Thanks !